# Android - How to create markers so that some are clickable and some are not?

Tags: android, google-maps

What is the best way to create markers on Google Maps so that for example, one marker can be clicked on to present the info window and another marker doesn’t allow clicks?

Comment: The best answer to your question would depend on your code and how you are adding markers. But if all you want is not to display the info window would to be not to set the `title` property of the `MarkerOption`.

Comment: @Barns, and what if a custom info window is being used?

Comment: Like I said the answer to your question depends on your code. I do not see your code, where your implement your "custom info window" or where you handle the `onClick` method of your marker. Without that no one can really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use the [onMarkerClick(Marker) callback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) to decide whether to consume the event (return true) or allow default behavior including info window (return false).

Consuming the event (return true) effectively disables clicking behavior for
that marker which was clicked; otherwise returning false produces the default "click" behavior which includes the info window.

The decision on whether to return true (consume) or false (default) would then be based on your specific implementation.

But for illustration purposes let's say you add a marker "tag" to each marker (*or just the markers you don't want to be clickable*) when adding markers and use that to make the decision...

```
    // Where you add markers
    Marker clickable = mMap.addMarker(
            new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.87364,151.20689))
                               .title("Clickable"));
    clickable.setTag(false);

    Marker notClickable = mMap.addMarker(
            new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-27.47093, 153.0235))
                               .title("Not Clickable"));
    notClickable.setTag(true);

    // This marker has no tag and therefore is handled in same manner as
    // false (default behavior).
    Marker anotherClickable = mMap.addMarker(
            new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-30.47093, 153.0235))
                               .title("Clickable 2"));


    // For simplicity an anonymous marker click listener is specified.
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

        // Return true if the click event is consumed (and therefore no
        // info window is displayed) or false to produce default behavior.

        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

            // Note that markers that have no tag (getTag() == null) get the
            //  default ("clickable") behavior

            return (marker != null && marker.getTag() != null && ((Boolean)marker.getTag()).booleanValue());
        }
    });
```